# Making Width and Height of a character in console equal in terms of pixels (C)

Tags: c, windows, console

I'm making a program in C (simple snake game).

I'm using window.h and came across an inconvenience.

I'm using COORD's and SetConsoleCursorPosition to move about the cursor.
However, moving one y coordinate is almost the same as moving two x coordinates in terms of how many pixels each represents.

For example, this square window has a width of 80 and height of 40 in terms of the cursor position coordinates. 
Also, you can clearly see the contraction (and therefore reduction of apparent speed of the snake) when moving sidewards in the images below.

Is there any efficient solution to this so that the pixel size of one move in the x direction is the same as one move in the y direction.

Many thanks.

[[image: Snake Moving Vertically [1]]

[image: Snake Moving Horizontally]

Comment: You mean, other than changing the size of the console window so that it is square? Use a ratio, multiply your movement vector by that.

Comment: Why do this at all? You can't really pipe or transfer low-level console IO so you might as well just create a normal GUI app. It will give you a higher maximum frame rate as well.

Comment: @Anders Because this is an assignment for my programming class and we have to meet certain criteria as well as being limited to a console application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) function lets you specify the console font size in the `lpConsoleCurrentFontEx`'s `dwFontSize` member. There you can set the font width and height be the same.

Comment: Not tried this yet, but if that's the case, that's brilliant it might be exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Update: Just integrated this into my program and it worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me on Windows 11 using Windows Terminal... https://gist.github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/09bad7baf75a7e6fa9b63b9f2e9c0069